# Joining meeting timeout issue on Zoom API

Tags: javascript, zoom-sdk

I’m using Academy LMS script with Academy LMS Live Class (zoom) Addon.
This addon asked me to enter api key and security key, I did.
Then I start a meeting via the zoom app and save the id and password to the system as a teacher.
When i try to connect a meeting as a student i get this error: “Joining meeting timeout. Your connection has timed out and you cannot join the meeting. Verify your network connectivity and try again.”

Please help me on this issue, thanks.

Thats my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Zoom</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/css/react-select.css"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/lib/vendor/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/lib/vendor/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/lib/vendor/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/lib/vendor/redux-thunk.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/lib/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.7/lib/vendor/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/zoom-meeting-1.7.7.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        start_zoom();
    });

   function start_zoom() {

    ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
    ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();


    testTool = window.testTool;

        var meetConfig = {
            apiKey: 'Existing Values',
            apiSecret: 'Existing Values',
            meetingNumber: 'Existing Values',
            userName: 'Existing Values',
            passWord: 'Existing Values',
        };


        var signature = ZoomMtg.generateSignature({
            meetingNumber: meetConfig.meetingNumber,
            apiKey: meetConfig.apiKey,
            apiSecret: meetConfig.apiSecret,
            role: 0,
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res.result);
            }
        });

        ZoomMtg.init({
            leaveUrl: "file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/zoom.html",
            isSupportAV: true,
            success: function () {
                ZoomMtg.join(
                    {
                        meetingNumber: meetConfig.meetingNumber,
                        userName: meetConfig.userName,
                        signature: signature,
                        apiKey: meetConfig.apiKey,
                        passWord: meetConfig.passWord,
                        success: function(res){
                            console.log('join meeting success');
                        },
                        error: function(res) {
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                    }
                );
            },
            error: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Error : “Joining meeting timeout. Your connection has timed out and you cannot join the meeting. Verify your network connectivity and try again”

Error Image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcANl.png)

Comment: Do I need to create a meeting with the keys ship account?

Comment: It worked when I updated the versions from 1.7.7 to 2.3.5(latest)